# how to check only one item in checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a check list box control and I want to select only one item at a time and I am currently using this code to do the same.

```
private void CLSTVariable_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  // Local variable
  int ListIndex;

  CLSTVariable.ItemCheck -= CLSTVariable_ItemCheck;

  for (ListIndex = 0; 
       ListIndex < CLSTVariable.Items.Count; 
       ListIndex++)
  {        
    // Unchecked all items that is not currently selected
    if (CLSTVariable.SelectedIndex != ListIndex)
    {
      // set item as unchecked
      CLSTVariable.SetItemChecked(ListIndex, false);
    } // if
    else
    {
      // set selected item as checked
      CLSTVariable.SetItemChecked(ListIndex, true);
    }
  } // for
  CLSTVariable.ItemCheck += CLSTVariable_ItemCheck;  
}
```

this code is working fine.

but problem is that when I click again and again on selected item then that selected item should not be unchecked, means at least one item should be checked always...

Comment: Why don't you use a `RadioButtonList` if you want just one item selected? Use the saw to saw and the screwdriver to drive screws...

Comment: Bazz, indeed. But I have to say that i 'often' find this kind of way to do one-tag-one-checkbox-solutions. Anyone who have a good reason of why, would please tag that to me! (Except cosmetic, which is a reason I can take).

Comment: I agree with Bazzz. Wrong tool for the job.  A key aspect of UX is that the user is very familiar with certain UI hints. Years of seeing checkboxes means they expect to be able to check multiple.If you enforce a single box being checked, it is a very jarring experience for the user.

Comment: @Ray Booysen: Agree, and besides that, going against the flow means that you end up in coding difficulties which result in asking questions on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with commentators above - you should consider using radiobuttons. But if you really need CheckedListBox, then use this ItemChecked event handler instead:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        Boolean isCheckedItemBeingUnchecked = (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked);
        if (isCheckedItemBeingUnchecked)
        {
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;
        }
        else
        {
            Int32 checkedItemIndex = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[0];
            checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedItemIndex, false);
            checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to change `e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;` to `e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;`. Otherwise you won't be able to uncheck already selected items.

Comment: @ChristianJunk, that's what author of the question wanted - at least one item should be always checked.

Answer (score 1):

*"at least one item should be checked always"*

The current solution (the last one) allows items to be checked off. If your purpose is to select exactly one item at all times, use this as a **MouseUp** event,

```
    private void ChklbBatchType_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = ((CheckedListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ((CheckedListBox)sender).Items.Count; ++ix)
            if (index != ix) { ((CheckedListBox)sender).SetItemChecked(ix, false);   }
              else ((CheckedListBox)sender).SetItemChecked(ix, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was an answer to me! I couldn't get the above code to work in the checkedListBox1_ItemCheck. I had to modify a portion of it ans include it in the checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event. But I couldn't remove the original code all together. Here is what I've added...

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 1)
        {
            Int32 checkedItemIndex = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[0];
            checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedItemIndex, false);
            checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
        }
    }
```

Which is basically, if you have more than 1 box checked, switch the last one for the new one. I'm curious why the original code didn't work. And why it has to be there for my new code to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code it work so well

```
private void chkboxmov_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < chkboxmov.Items.Count; ++ix)
        if (ix != e.Index)
            chkboxmov.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
}
```